# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'

Tags: python, regression, typeerror

I'm trying to do a regression, but it does not allow me to multiply my values within the exponential function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import math

data = pd.read_csv("/Users/Bruno/PycharmProjects/Benzoic Acid/BA Basic 
Data/Rot-Disc-016.xlsx-Table 1.csv")
len_d = len(data.iloc[2:,0])

t = []
Benz = []
DC = []
dC = []

for i in range(len_d):
    t.append(float(data.iloc[2+i,0]))
    Benz.append(float(data.iloc[2+i,4]))
    DC.append( float(data.iloc[1+len_d,4])-float(data.iloc[2+i,4]) )
    dC.append(float(data.iloc[2+i,5]))

def obj(beta, x, y):
    beta_0 = beta[0] #This will allow the elements to be converted into beta vectors
    beta_1 = beta[1]
    yhat = beta_0 * np.exp( x * beta_1 ) #This is the choosen model equation
    resids = yhat - y #Will calculate residues
    SSR = np.sum(resids**2) #Will produce the sum of the square residues(SSR)
    return SSR


result = scipy.optimize.minimize(obj, x0=[1,1], args=(t, DC )) #This 
optimizes the intended function
beta_opt = result.x
```

Comment: Problem is about multiplying a list by a float. Have you seen this article [Python can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994648/python-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-float)?